# Using Mojarra 2.2 with WebSphere 9

Tags: websphere, jsf-2.2, mojarra

I'm trying to configure WebSphere 9 to use Mojarra 2.2 and this is what I've done so far:

**1 - Created a Shared Library named Faces pointing to Mojarra files:**
[image: Shared Library]

**2 - Changed the JSF implementation for the application to use Mojarra:**
[image: JSF Implementation]

**3 - Changed classloading settings:**
[image: Classloading settings]

**4 - Included the newly created library in the Shared Libraries References:**
[image: Shared Libraries References]

However, when I start the server, I see the following message on SystemOut.log:

```
[07-06-2016 10:43:44:467 BST] 0000005e application   E   Unable to obtain com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIExtension from CDI implementation.  Flows described with javax.faces.flow.builder.FlowDefinition are unavailable.
```

And the following on SystemErr.log:

```
[07-06-2016 10:14:44:905 BST] 0000005e SystemErr     R java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.
[07-06-2016 10:14:44:906 BST] 0000005e SystemErr     R   at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:270)
```

What am I missing? Isn't Mojarra 2.2 compatible with WebSphere 9?
I've already tried dozens of different combinations (MyFaces 2.2, MyFaces 2.0, parent first for classloader, parent last for classloader, isolated classloader for the library, etc), but they all failed.
Needless to say that all my CDI beans are causing the following error:

```
Target unreachable, identifier 'whatever' resolved to null
```

Comment: Did you added listener to web.xml? Check this [page](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tweb_jsf22.html) for more details.

Comment: @Gas, yes, I added the listener (I tried both ways). In fact, I even tried setting MyFaces listener just to check if the error message changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for answering my own question, but I'm now using the official release (instead of the beta version) and, apparently, what I was trying to achieve is no longer possible:

[image]

The option to choose SunRI1.2 was removed from the dropdown.